# Access data array in multiple routes angular 4

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, routes, rxjs

I have a service which has some data stored like this and functions that push data to it:

**service.ts**

```
export class SongsService {
        albumsChanged = new Subject();

        //Define future album name and songs list
           newAlbumName:any;
           newSongs:any;
           newAlbumID:any;

        // New album object    
           albumData:{name: string, songs:Array<string>};

           albums = [
            {
                name: 'One album',
                songs: [
                    'song1 Album 1',
                    'song2 Album 1',
                    'song3 Album 1',
                ]
        }];

        albumSongs(albumID){
           return this.http.get('http://api.musicgraph.com/api/v2/album/'+
           albumID +'/tracks?"+ api_key + "&limit=30").map(
              (res:Response) => {   
           const songData = res.json();     

        // func to get all tracks
        var tracks = songData.data.map(a => a.title);
        // Function to filter repeated songs
        var uTracks = tracks.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
          return index == self.indexOf(elem);
        });
        return this.allTracks= uTracks;
       }
      );
    }

   // .subscribe(album => {console.log(album)}) returns []
   newAlbum(name:string){
   name = name.replace(/ /g, '+');
   var albumID= '';
   this.http.
   get('http://api.musicgraph.com/api/v2/album/suggest?'
   api_key + '&limit=2&prefix=' + name)  
   .subscribe(      
   ( res:Response) => { 
        var rawData = res.json();       
        // console.log(rawData);
        var albumName:string = rawData.data[0].title;
        albumID = rawData.data[0].id;

        this.albumSongs(albumID).subscribe(

            songs => {
            this.newSongs = songs;
            console.log("And this are the songs in newAlbum = " + this.newSongs );
            this.albumData = {
                name:albumName,
                songs:this.newSongs
            };
            this.albums.push(this.albumData)
            this.albumsChanged.next(this.albums.slice())
            }
        );
    }
  );
  this.albumsChanged.next(this.albums.slice());
}

        newAlbum (name:string) {
       //function that gets album name from api
          this.albums.push(albumObj);
          this.albumsChanged.next(this.albums.slice());
        }
```

I have set my **app.component** to run an init function as a seed:

```
    import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { SongsComponent } from './songs/songs.component';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { SongsService } from './songs.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      providers: []
    })
    export class AppComponent {
        albums:any = [];

        constructor(private songsService: SongsService){
        };


        ngOnInit() {
            this.songsService.init()    
    }

    }
```

**App.module**

```
     const appRoutes: Routes =[
        {path: '', component: AlbumsComponent},
        {path: ':album', component: SongsComponent},
      ];

      @NgModule({
        declarations: [
          SongsComponent,
          AppComponent,
          AlbumsComponent    
        ],
        imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          FormsModule,
          RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
          HttpModule
        ],
        providers: [SongsService],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      })
      export class AppModule {}
```

When I console.log(this.albums) in the next component it only has the seed I hard coded on service.ts.

**Albums.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-albums',
      templateUrl: './albums.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./albums.component.css'],
      providers: []
    })
    export class AlbumsComponent {

     @ViewChild('albumInput') albumInput: ElementRef;
     @ViewChild('deleteIcon') deleteIcon: ElementRef;

        private albums:{name: string, songs:Array<string>}[] = [];
        private subscription: Subscription;

        constructor(private songsService: SongsService,
                    private router: Router){};

     ngOnInit() {
            this.albums = this.songsService.albums;
            this.subscription = this.songsService.albumsChanged
            .subscribe(
                (albums:{name: string, songs:Array<string>}[]) => {
                    this.albums = albums;
                });
            console.log(this.albums);
     }

        albumslog(){
            console.log(this.albums)
        }

        // albumSongs(){
        //  this.router.navigate([])
        // }

      deleteAlbum(indexOfAlbum){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(indexOfAlbum);
        this.songsService.albums.splice(indexOfAlbum,1);

      addAlbum(albumName){
        this.songsService.newAlbum(albumName);
        console.log(this.songsService.albums);
```

And **songs.components**:

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'app-songs',
      templateUrl: './songs.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./songs.component.css'],
      providers: []
    })

    export class SongsComponent implements OnInit {
       private subscription: Subscription;
       private albums:any;
       private album:any;
       private songs:Array<string>;
       private albumIndex:string;

      constructor(private songsService: SongsService,
                  private router: Router,
                  private route: ActivatedRoute){};

      ngOnInit() {
        var albumIndex = +this.route.snapshot.params['album'];
        console.log(albumIndex);
        this.albums = this.songsService.albums;
         this.subscription = this.songsService.albumsChanged
         .subscribe(
           (albums:{name: string, songs:Array<string>}[]) => {
             this.albums = albums;
             this.songs = this.getAlbum(albumIndex);

           });
         console.log(this.albums);
        this.getAlbum(albumIndex);
        // console.log(this.songsService.getAlbum("Así en el Cielo Como en la Selva"))
        console.log(this.songs);
      }

      getAlbum(index: number){
        return this.album = this.albums.splice(index)
```

Therefore, when I go to another route my `service.albums` from my service is empty, how can I keep this data over many routes?

Comment: It's great that you left out the most important function: this.songsService.init(). well done. Show us what it does.

Comment: It's actually what is commented , the newAlbum() function is the funny one, will update forthelols

Comment: Have you listed the SongsService as a provider in your module?

Comment: Your entire code makes no sense.. this.songsService.init() is not defined. commented this.newAlbum("sams town"); would give a nullpointer. your newAlbum function gives a nullpointer because albumObj doesnt exist.  etc etc etc

Comment: You shouldn't be initing your songsService in your component, you should be doing that in your Service ngOnInit, so when the (singleton) service initialized, you setup your variables, and they your components interact with already an already initialized state. The component should only be getting the songs list, and potentially adding songs to the list, but service initialization should be happening in the service.

Comment: Sorry, I updated. Was obviating some not obvious code. I thought services only had constructors, not OnInit function. Would this keep the array avilable in other routes?

Comment: @Carsten you need to chill out. Comments like that "It's great that you left out the most important function: this.songsService.init(). well done." or also "Your entire code makes no sense" when someone take time to write a good question but forgot few things... Really? If you feel the need to be like that about a question, move to another.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith Yes I added it, apparently I don't understand quite well the service lifecycle. OnInit would make it available when changing routes? Or the other way around, would OnDestroy be called when I change route?
This is my first angular app, I appreciate good feedback, I know the code has issues, pointing them out that way is't quite helping.

Comment: Ok, I added that init function to the constructor and works ok, but when I change the route my albums array returns the hard coded object.Any advice on how to keep this data when moving around?